# Why is my function not found?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, omnifaces

Here is my code

```
<html (...) xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">
 ...
<c:set var="formattedDate"
    value="#{of:formatDate(now, 'dd/MM/yyyy')}" />
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
value="#{of:formatDate(now, 'dd/MM/yyyy')}" Function 'of:formatDate' not found
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
```

Here is my **pom.xml**

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>JSFPlayground</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Do you have the `of` namespace set ?

Comment: Are you sure the Omnifaces libs are in the classpath ? Can you try running `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: @kocko You're my life saver :) Effectively, Eclipse didn't include the jars inmy web app ! Thanks.

Comment: @kocko Do it quickly... because I was just about to delete the question... :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the Omnifaces lib has not been added to the classpath.

`mvn clean install` should do the trick.

Comment: In fact, Eclipse copmpletly ignored the Maven Libraries. I had to add them by doing **Project Properties** > Deployment Assembly and then add the Maven Libraries.